# Jenkins job to configure job

Tags: python, jenkins

To create the job in Jenkins, I am using the below command and it throws the below error. Any one can suggest for the solution.

```
jenkins-jobs --conf /etc/jenkins_jobs/jenkins_jobs.ini update /etc/jenkins_jobs/jobs
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: Support for python 2.6 is deprecated and will be removed.
  warnings.warn("Support for python 2.6 is deprecated and will be removed.")
INFO:root:Updating jobs in ['/etc/jenkins_jobs/jobs'] ([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jenkins-jobs", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/cmd.py", line 191, in main
    execute(options, config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/cmd.py", line 372, in execute
    n_workers=options.n_workers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 333, in update_jobs
    self.load_files(input_fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 230, in load_files
    self.parser = YamlParser(self.global_config, self.plugins_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 226, in plugins_list
    self._plugins_list = self.jenkins.get_plugins_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 190, in get_plugins_info
    raise e
jenkins.NotFoundException: Requested item could not be found
INFO:jenkins_jobs.builder:Cache saved
```

Thanks in advance!